# Math. Sorting. Do "n * (n + 1) / 2" always less than "n * n"?

Tags: c, sorting, math

Please see code below. The code sorts an array in exactly n * (n + 1) / 2 iterations. I took the formula from Wikipedia [1 + 2 + 3 + 4 +...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF). No need to prove it, lets assume it just works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int A[] = {3,1,4,8,6,17};
int nruns = 0;

#define N sizeof(A) / sizeof(int)

int imin(int idx){
 int im = idx;
 for(int i = idx; i < N; ++i, ++nruns)
  if(A[i] < A[im])im = i;
 return im;
}

int swap(li, ri){
 int t = A[li];
 A[li] = A[ri];
 A[ri] = t;
 return 0;
}

int main()
{
 int im;
 for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
  im = imin(i);
  swap(i, im);
 }

 for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  printf("%d ", A[i]);
 printf("\nN = %d\nN*N = %d\nnruns = %d\n", N, N*N, nruns);

 /*
  (n*n + n) / 2 < n*n
  Is above always true ?
 */

 return 0;
}
```

[This code at OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/rJyE4MeIV)

My question is, is it always true that "n * (n + 1) / 2" is less than "n * n" ?

Comment: This is true for all real n in (-infinity, 0) U (1, +infinity)

Comment: @ForceBru Care to share a proof ?

Comment: I cheated and [asked WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Is+(n+*+(n+%2B+1))+%2F+2+less+than+(n+*+n)+for+all+n%3F)

Comment: simply solve the inequality `n(n + 1)/2 < n²` or `2n² > n² + n` which is equivalent to `n² - n > 0`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about math and not programming

Comment: @phuclv For me, as a programmer, it is easier to ask a question in terms of programming. So people know how did I come to asking.

Comment: the fact that you're a programmer doesn't mean that this is on-topic. The answers are pure math

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose `n > 0`. Then, if `n * (n + 1) / 2 < n * n` is true, `(n + 1) / 2 < n` is also true, thus, `n + 1 < 2 * n`, so `n > 1`. If `(n > 0) AND (n > 1)`, then `n > 1`.

Suppose `n < 0`. Then, if `n * (n + 1) / 2 < n * n` is true, `(n + 1) / 2 > n` is also true, thus, `n + 1 > 2 * n`, so `n < 1`. If `(n < 0) AND (n < 1)` then `n < 0`.

Which means that this is true if `(n > 1) OR (n < 0)`.

Comment: Thanks. I could have did such myself. Maybe I am just not so good at thinking in terms of algebra. I had little time to fiddle with the math though.

Comment: Trivia - for "proof", reverse the series and add it to get 2x the series: (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n-1 + n ) + (n + n-1 + n-2 + ... + 2 + 1) = (n+1) + (n+1) + ... + (n+1), that's n terms, and the series was added to itself for 2x the sum, so the formula is sum = ((n+1)(n))/2.

Comment: @rcgldr That is smart, sir.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose *n* is real and *n* < 0 or *n* > 1.

*n*•(*n*+1)/2 < *n*<sup>2</sup> if and only if there is a positive *h* such that *n*•(*n*+1)/2 + *h* = *n*<sup>2</sup>.

So *h* would be *n*<sup>2</sup> − *n*•(*n*+1)/2. Is this positive? It equals *n*<sup>2</sup>/2 − *n*/2. If *n* < 0, both *n*<sup>2</sup>/2 and *n*/2 are positive, so *h* is positive. If *n* > 1, *n*<sup>2</sup>/2 − *n*/2 = *n*•(*n*−1)/2, and both *n* and (*n*−1)/2 are positive, so *h* is positive. So, for *n* < 0 or *n* > 1, *n*•(*n*+1)/2 < *n*<sup>2</sup>.

On the other hand, if 0 ≤ *n* ≤ 1, we have *h* = *n*•(*n*−1)/2, and we can see that *n* is positive or zero while (*n*−1)/2 is negative or zero, so *h* is not positive, so *n*•(*n*+1)/2 ≥ *n*<sup>2</sup>.